# can we have 2 tabview in an app android

Tags: android, user-interface, tabview

In my App I m required to have 2 tabViews one at top and the other is at bottom like i-phone apps. In android can we have the same views? please guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a Tab inside a Tab in Android. You can create a Tab and on the First Tab give the  TabActivity of the second Tab. So, when you will open the Tab it will have another Tab also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have it.The only thing you need to do is to add the second tabhost as the child of one of the tabs in your first one. I've tried that once so it should be working.